# how can i debug these rsync errors

Tags: linux, rsync

I've been trying to get rsync working to keep track of files from a web server (linux) to my windows desktop.

Both the server and my machine has rsync installed. I am trying to pull files from the server down to my local machine, just the ones that have changed or update since I pushed them to the server as it's a file based CMS running.

If I run: `rsync -avn -e "ssh -p [port]" [user]@[ip]:~/public_html/ ./` - So I am hoping that this will copy files from the `/public_html/` folder so the current directory I am running from the command from.

The errors I get are:

```
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.3]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [Receiver]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(231) [Receiver=3.2.7]
```

I've read that a server and localhost can have different versions and still run ok, and some people suggest directory issues but the directory exists. How can I debug this more?

Comment: Not about programming, so off-topic. Check your firewall. Can you `ssh` into the remote machine ok? Try `ssh -vvv` to get debug output from ssh.

Comment: Is the extra "i" in "puiblic_html" a typo in the actual command?

Comment: @GordonDavisson sorry typo in the question, not what I was running in the Console. Robert, Yes I can SSH into the remote machine OK.

Comment: I am in the same situation. Have you solved the problem?